# How to get UITableViewStyle inside UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview, cell

I had tried check inside cell backgroundView, but for both styles (UITableViewStylePlain, UITableViewStyleGrouped) were equal to NOT nil. There is whether any way to get UITableViewStyle from inside UITableViewCell?

**SOLVED:**
I just added to cell constructor a variable of type UITableViewStyle and set it when created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, your cell shouldn't care what the style is.

But if you must know, your best bet is to do something like this:

```
UIView *tv = self;
while (tv && ![tv isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) tv = tv.superview;
UITableViewStyle style = [(UITableView *)tv style];
```

Comment: Thanks, @Anomie, this works but only if cell already in UITableView, but me need to know a table style yet until adding cell to UITableView (I forgot say this in a question).

Comment: @RomanShkarin: The style is controlled by the UITableView, not the cell. So until the cell is in the UITableView, there *isn't* any style.